# How can I parse an associative array using Gson Converter in Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm receiving a `JSON` response from a PHP server. In android, I need to write a java model (POJO) to use to parse the response in Retrofit (An Android library for http-requests).

JSON Structure:

```
{
  "calendar": {
    "2016-06-10": [
      {
        "time": "10h00m",
        "title": "PROVA P2",
        "description": "LP / RED / ED.FIS - 80 E 90",
        "color": "#990000"
      }
    ],
    "2016-06-11": [
      {
        "time": "10h00m",
        "title": "SIMULADO",
        "description": "LOREM PSIUM DOLOR LOREM",
        "color": "#009900"
      },
      {
        "time": "11h00m",
        "title": "CONSELHO DE CLASSE",
        "description": "LOREM PSIUM DOLOR",
        "color": "#009900"
      }
    ]
  },
  "error": false
}
```

This `JSON` is from PHP Server.
How can I handle it using **Retrofit**?

Answer (score 6):

To parse `JSON` with dynamic keys, you will need a `Map` in your `POJO` class.

Add the following `POJO` classes to your project:

1. `CalendarResponse.java`

   ```
   public class CalendarResponse {
     @SerializedName("calendar")
     Map<String, List<Entry>> entries;

     @SerializedName("error")
     private boolean error;
   }
   ```
2. `Entry.java`

   ```
   public class Entry {
     @SerializedName("time")
     private String time;

     @SerializedName("title")
     private String title;

     @SerializedName("description")
     private String description;

     @SerializedName("color")
     private String color;
   }
   ```
3. Use the `CalendarResponse` class in your retrofit interface for your endpoint, see example below

   ```
   public interface CalendarService {
     @GET("<insert your own relative url>")
     Call<CalendarResponse> listCalendar();
   }
   ```
4. Execute the call (synchronously) as follows:

   ```
   Call<CalendarResponse> call = calendarService.listCalendar();
   CalendarResponse result = call.execute().body();
   ```

If needed, here is an example to parse the `JSON` with `GSON`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
CalendarResponse b = gson.fromJson(json, CalendarResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would create a POJO which is a representation of your JSON, but in this case, you would need a 2016-06-10 class and a 2016-06-11 class.

This isn't a solution. Therefore, change the JSON response to make the date a separate value:

```
{
  "calendar": [
    {
      "date": "2016-06-10",
      "entries": [
        {
          "time": "10h00m",
          "title": "PROVA P2",
          "description": "LP / RED / ED.FIS - 80 E 90",
          "color": "#990000"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Better yet, just make one dateTime value and make it a proper [ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/389649) timestamp while you're at it:

```
{
  "calendar": [
      {
        "time": "2016-06-10T08:00:00.000Z",
        "title": "PROVA P2",
        "description": "LP / RED / ED.FIS - 80 E 90",
        "color": "#990000"
      }
    ]
}
```

If you have no control over the server serving the JSON then you should use Retrofit to just get a String and do the Gson conversion yourself via gson.

Answer (score 0):

What I does when I don't want to create a `POJO` for a weird response from the server is keep it as a `JSON` in java and parse the string to create a JSON object. *(Yes because sometimes we just can't control what the API guy is coding...)*

As *Cristan* said, it would be strange to create a `2016-06-10` class. So, better handle it directly as a `JSON` object for that particular case. You can access any attribute using a JSON container and even store it in a database that way.

**What you need to do if you choose that path:**

```
private String sendAlert(String lat, String lon) throws IOException, JSONException {

    Call<ResponseBody> call = cougarServices.postAlert(lat, lon);
    ResponseBody response = call.execute().body();
    JSONObject json = (response != null ? new JSONObject(response.string()) : null);
    return handleJsonRequest(json);

}
```