# convert a json object response into array and get both key and value android

Tags: android, json, key-value

I have a json response which is dynamic such that even the key name and index no.can change

```
{
"Assigned": {
    "DC": 7,
    "EmpCode": "E0104",
    "FS": 8
}
}
```

I want to convert it into JsonArray and fetch all the key names and values dynamically under the object 'Assigned'.But I am only getting the value name by trying this.

```
try {
                        //converting dynamic jsonobject to json array and fetching value as well as key name
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("Assigned");
                        Iterator x = jsonObject.keys();
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                        while (x.hasNext()) {
                            String key = (String) x.next();
                            jsonArray.put(jsonObject.get(key));
                    }
                        Toast.makeText(RolesActivity.this,jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("jsonarray",jsonArray.toString());

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(RolesActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: that is completely wrong API architecture - to use json object as json array. *Correct* solution is to fix it on backend

Comment: that api is being used by website and other applications as well so cant ask that to be edited.I need to work with that only.please help

Comment: only if I get the corresponding key name and value dynamically,my job will be done

Comment: try using hashmap.!

Comment: cant u please edit the code and put a sample code of hashmap here?

Comment: Possibly similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883748/how-can-i-parse-an-associative-array-using-gson-converter-in-retrofit

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `JSONObject`'s keys list by calling [`JSONObject.keys()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys()) (as `Iterator`), or [`JSONObject.names()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()) (as `JSONArray`)

After that you can iterate through the keys, and get each key's value by using [`JSONObject.getString(key)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String))

Comment: get(key) is actually giving me the value.please edit the code and post it

Comment: @user8601021, `get(key) is actually giving me the value` that's right, and I just told how to get the keys in my answer

Comment: i want the key name

Comment: @user8601021, that is completely clear to me, and the methods I have posted return **the Iterator through the key names** and **JSONArray of the key names**

Answer (score 0):

First create a pojo class

```
  private HashMap<String, String> parseResponse(){

    String json = ""; //  your json string

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Response response =  gson.fromJson(json, Response.class)

    return response.getAssigned();

}


public class Response {

    @SerializedName("Assigned")
    private HashMap<String, String> assigned;

    public HashMap<String, String> getAssigned() {
        return assigned;
    }
}
```

than parse with Gson library. You can read key and values from assigned Hashmap.

Comment: please post the complete code.I have not used gson before

Comment: Check my updated answer. And this is the Gson github link https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: i will try 2moro.have to go now